# Weak property deallocation confusion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using a third party library and it required setting a delegate. In this scenario I want to set the delegate to be another class so I go to write

```
ThirdPartyLibrary.delegate = MyDelegateHandlerClass()
```

But Xcode (Xcode 10 beta) gives me a warning saying:

> Instance will be immediately deallocated because property ‘delegate’
>   is ‘weak’

Clicking into the `delegate` of the third party library I see that it is indeed defined as `weak` as follows:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ThirdPartyLibraryDelegate> delegate;
```

However, if I change my initial setting of the delegate to:

```
let someInstance = MyDelegateHandlerClass()
ThirdPartyLibrary.delegate = someInstance
```

Then I get no warning? How are these two not the same thing? Just looking for advice and an explanation really. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested, this warning was recently implemented in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14875 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are, in effect, the same thing.  Once `someInstance` goes out of scope the delegate handler will be released and the delegate property of the library will become `nil`.

In the first case the compiler can see that the result of an allocation is being assigned to a `weak` property and warn you that it will be immediately released, which is probably not what you want.

In the second case it sees the assignment to a local variable and so the object will remain in memory for some time. The compiler cannot determine that you didn't want the object to be released at the end of the function, which means that it doesn't warn you.

You will need to store a strong reference to the delegate handler in a property

Comment: Ah makes sense! Now let's say all of this is going on in a struct, at the top of the struct I could just declare `private static let someInstance = MyDelegateHandlerClass()` and then assign that to the `delegate` and that would be ok?

Answer (score 0):

You get no warning in second case, but it will get deallocated as well, because `someInstance` is a local variable - will be deallocated when you leave the scope where it was declared.

What you need to do is store your `MyDelegateHandlerClass` instance somewhere. If you are certain that you will use only one instance of `MyDelegateHandlerClass`, you can use a Singleton pattern:

```
class MyDelegateHandlerClass : ThirdPartyLibraryDelegate
{
    static let sharedInstance = MyDelegateHandlerClass()

    // class implementation
}

(...)

ThirdPartyLibrary.delegate = MyDelegateHandlerClass.sharedInstance
```